# Proper way to imitate UISplitviewController's _detailitem behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have two container views on my view, trying to immitate split view controller tableview on the left side and detail view on the right side. When use `didselect` row on masters `tableview`,  detail view should show some details

Problem is when I pass the data to detail view controllers instance, it always returns null.

on master:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) LogDetailViewController *wods;
UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    self.wods= [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LogDetailViewController"];
//also tried self.wods= [[LogDetailViewController alloc] init];
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //one of the if else method rest of it was too long
     else if ([indexPath section]==1){
        GIRLS *girls =[self.girlsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        self.wods.girls = girls;
        self.wods.section=1;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshLOGDetails" object:nil];
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

in detail:

```
@property  int section;
@property (nonatomic, strong) GIRLS *girls;
//refresh notification
extern NSString * const NOTIF_refreshLOGDetails;
@synthesize section;
@synthesize girls;

- (void)refreshLOGDetails:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"Notification refreshLOGDetails works");
    [self configureView];
}
- (void)configureView
{  
 //also tried self.girls and self.section 
  NSLog(@"Section is %i",section);
  NSLog(@"configure view object %@",girls);

}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Notification refreshLOGDetails works
Section is 0
configure view object (null)
```

What is it am I doing wrong? Why do I get null values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're creating a new instance of the LogDetailViewController when you instantiate it or use alloc init. If you set these up as controllers in a container view in the storyboard, then you need to reference the one that was created there, not create a new one. You can use self.parentViewController to get a reference to the controller with the container views in it. self.parentViewController.childViewControllers will give you an array which should contain master and detail -- you just need to get the correct one out of that array and return it.

Comment: I get your point you are right , I have solved the problem with singleton class, but I wonder why when I call `NSArray *viewControllers = self.parentViewController.childViewControllers;
  NSLog(@"View Controllers %@",viewControllers);` in container views I get null value

Comment: @MordFustang, I don't know -- you shouldn't. You didn't really describe how you set things up in IB, so I can't tell. IF that code is in a controller that's truly a child view controller, then you shouldn't get null.